# Selection sort only passing once

Tags: sorting, selection

Hi am trying to create a selection sort but it only appears to pass through once 
the first debug displays this
3,2,10,9,5,   which is correct
then the second debug displays this
2,0,0,0,0 
and the last one displays this
3,0,10,9,5,

as you can see it only appears to go though the loop once instead of the 4 times that i am telling it to what am i doing wrong?

```
int[] List = new int[] {3, 2, 10, 9, 5};//List 
    int[] ListB = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};//ListB

    Debug.Log(List[0] + ","+List[1] + ","+List[2] + ","+List[3] + ","+List[4] + ",");
    int minimum,temp;//2 new ints

    for (int outer = 0; outer <  List.Length-1; outer++)//Loop for 0 to number of ints in list -1
    {
        minimum = outer;//set minimum to outer

        for (int inner = 0; inner <  List.Length; inner++)//loop for how many ints are in the list
        {
            if (List[inner] < List[minimum])// if list inner < list minimum 
            {
                minimum = inner;//set minimum to inner
            }                                          
        }
        ListB[outer] = List[minimum];//listb outer = list minimum
        List[minimum] = 0;//set the list minimum to a dummy value 
    }
    Debug.Log(ListB[0] + ","+ListB[1] + ","+ListB[2] + ","+ListB[3] + ","+ListB[4]);
    Debug.Log(List[0] + ","+List[1] + ","+List[2] + ","+List[3] + ","+List[4] + ",");
```

Comment: after adding a couple more debugs in it does apear to do the orignal loop 4 times as it should

Comment: ok so it loops 4 times and does the first swap into the second array but after that it just stops swapping them in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set the list[minimum] to 0 the next time the loop execute will find 0 as the minimum value
you have another thing to notice, First loop should finish at list.length
this is the true code

```
int[] List = new int[] { 3, 2, 10, 9, 5 };//List 
        int[] ListB = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };//ListB

        Debug.log(List[0] + "," + List[1] + "," + List[2] + "," + List[3] + "," + List[4] + ",");
        int minimum, temp;//2 new ints

        for (int outer = 0; outer < List.Length ; outer++)//Loop for 0 to number of ints in list -1
        {
            minimum = outer;//set minimum to outer

            for (int inner = 0; inner < List.Length; inner++)//loop for how many ints are in the list
            {
                if (List[inner] < List[minimum])// if list inner < list minimum 
                {
                    minimum = inner;//set minimum to inner
                }
            }
            ListB[outer] = List[minimum];//listb outer = list minimum
            List[minimum] = int.MaxValue;//set the list minimum to a dummy value 
        }
        Debug.log(ListB[0] + "," + ListB[1] + "," + ListB[2] + "," + ListB[3] + "," + ListB[4]);
        Debug.log(List[0] + "," + List[1] + "," + List[2] + "," + List[3] + "," + List[4] + ",");
```

Comment: Just change int.max to the equivalent in your programming language @pvtctrlalt

Comment: thanks very much alloush i wasnt sure what to put in the list[minimum] part as the pseudocode i was working from just said dummy value so i put 0 thanks for point that out